# Payload file does not exist in nuget package

Tags: c#, xaml, nuget

I tried running the xaml-controls-gallery from github. it require to have the latest windows sdk (18xxx) 1909h2 installed. I also installed nuget package microsoft.ui.xaml-prerelease-200422001. But when i compile i got the following error: I verified and it indeed is not on my file system.

Error       Payload file 'C:\Users\Intel.nuget\packages\microsoft.ui.xaml\2.4.0-prerelease.200422001\runtimes\win10-x86\native\Microsoft.UI.Xaml\Themes\rs4_generic.xaml' does not exist.  XamlControlsGallery
Error       Payload file 'C:\Users\Intel.nuget\packages\microsoft.ui.xaml\2.4.0-prerelease.200422001\runtimes\win10-x86\native\Microsoft.UI.Xaml\Themes\rs5_compact_themeresources.xaml' does not exist.   XamlControlsGallery
Error       Payload file 'C:\Users\Intel.nuget\packages\microsoft.ui.xaml\2.4.0-prerelease.200422001\runtimes\win10-x86\native\Microsoft.UI.Xaml\Themes\rs3_compact_themeresources.xaml' does not exist.   XamlControlsGallery
Error       Payload file 'C:\Users\Intel.nuget\packages\microsoft.ui.xaml\2.4.0-prerelease.200422001\runtimes\win10-x86\native\Microsoft.UI.Xaml\Themes\rs2_compact_themeresources.xaml' does not exist.   XamlControlsGallery
Error       Payload file 'C:\Users\Intel.nuget\packages\microsoft.ui.xaml\2.4.0-prerelease.200422001\runtimes\win10-x86\native\Microsoft.UI.Xaml\Themes\19h1_compact_themeresources.xaml' does not exist.  XamlControlsGallery

Can any one help me go through this error?